# How can I run markdown on my website?

Tags: markdown

Apologies, if this question is somewhat basic, but research on internet has not yielded any reasonable answers. I want to be able to run markdown on my website, similar to what github has (edit/preview setup) or actually something very similar to stackoverflow. I found a number of articles on the history of markdown including:
[

- [Daring Firebal](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) which does not provide more info
- Life hacker's article which allows running MD on your local machine using a perl script
- [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-future-of-markdown/) - with a project of great ambition, yet still not explaining how I can run their version of MD on my website

And a few more sources. Some allow writing markdown online and sync to gdrive, but again that's not what I'm looking for.

I'm not looking to creating my own flavor, I particularly like [Stackedit](https://stackedit.io/editor)
because it allows flowcharts.

Do I need a "markdown server"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of ways in which you can 'run Markdown' on your website. For a large part, it depends on your web server's environment. Below is a basic summary of the options:

- Run a traditional 'live' server.

  In this scenario, each request made to the server runs a script which retrieves the Markdown text,  converts it to HTML, does some possible post-prepossessing (running through a templating system), and then returns the HTML at an HTTP response.

  This could be as simple as writing a CGI script, or as complicated as using a (server side) web framework. In either case, the available options will depend on which  server you are running, which scripting languages you have valuable, which Markdown [implementation](https://github.com/markdown/markdown.github.com/wiki/Implementations) you want to use and the list goes on.
- Use a static site generator.

  This requires you to install a piece of software on your local machine, and then organize your Markdown files in a particular manner (along with a template and theme, etc). Then you would run a command-line script which would convert all your Markdown files to HTML files. You can then upload those files to a 'flat file server' (almost any web server will do), and your files will be served much more efficiently. Next time you want to make edits/additions, just make the changes to your local Markdown files and run the script again and re-upload. Some of the more advanced scripts will even automate the uploading for you. You can find a [few](https://www.staticgen.com/) [lists](https://staticsitegenerators.net/) of such packages with a quick search.

As SO is not the place to make tool recommendations, that is about all the help I can provide. If you can narrow down which approach you want to take,then you should be able to narrow your research.
For tool recommendations, try [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).